# Does selling shares within 30 days of purchase count as a wash sale?

Tags: united-states, taxes, wash-sale

Quoting [IRS publication 550](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550#en_US_2018_publink100010601),

> A wash sale occurs when you sell or trade stock or securities at a
>   loss and within 30 days before or after the sale you:
>
> 1. Buy substantially identical stock or securities,
> 2. Acquire substantially identical stock or securities in a fully taxable trade,
> 3. Acquire a contract or option to buy substantially identical stock or securities, or
> 4. Acquire substantially identical stock for your individual retirement arrangement (IRA) or Roth IRA.

Suppose I buy 100 shares of a stock on July 1, and two weeks later, on July 15, sell those shares at a price lower than I paid for them. I have sold stock at a loss, and I have not made any purchase of replacement shares - I own 0 shares at the end. However, the purchase through which I acquired the sold shares falls within 30 days before the sale. This purchase is a purchase of shares identical to those I sold, because those shares *are* the shares I sold.

Does the purchase through which I acquired the shares I sold count as buying "substantially identical stock or securities" within 30 days before the sale, thus disallowing the loss? I feel like it shouldn't, but laws can get really weird. Citations would be appreciated, the more explicit the better.

Comment: In thinking about it, I see your confusion, because it says "before or after the sale" - this is meant to cover the situation where you buy 100 stock, buy 100 more stock, then sell 100 stock and claim you were in fact selling the first 100 stock and thus claim a loss. But I can see how you could read the quote as including this, so +1 for a surprisingly non-obvious implication of the wording.

Comment: Your citation seems sufficient, it's not purchase of sold stock, but purchase of stock or securities that are substantially identical to those sold. Moreover the intent behind wash sale rules makes no sense without multiple purchases at play.

Comment: @HartCO There's two ways you could handle this. You could draft the rules such that this doesn't count as a wash sale. Or you could draft the rules such that this does count as a wash sale but the consequences are the correct consequences for this case. Congress happens to have chosen the latter approach. See 26 USC 1091(a).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not sure what you're talking about, there can't be a wash sale with only one purchase.

Comment: @HartCO Did you read 1091(a)? It only requires one purchase. Congress chose to define a wash sale incredibly broadly. (And the statements you get from many brokers *will* identify this as a wash sale and will *also* increase the basis as it is both the wash sale and where the increased basis appears.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That indicates other shares acquired, I should have said "one purchase/acquisition" to be more specific, but my point was that OP's citation covers it.

Comment: @HartCO Why do you say it indicates "other" shares acquired? The word "other" does not appear in there nor does anything else limit the scope of the other transaction. And, in fact, brokers *do* report this as a wash sale (as we saw in the other question that I'm pretty sure we had this same discussion on unless I'm remembering incorrectly).

Comment: This is a duplicate, I’m certain. I just need to find the original.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I meant another acquisition, even if via exchange, which the citation in OP covers

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I may be remembering wrong, but I remember the question you are talking about. I think it was closed as it was asking purely theoretically about the law and not about how it affected a real situation but I could be misremembering.

Comment: @Vality - the question I recall suggested that a broker's paperwork noted a wash sale, but since there were no remain shares, OP was permitted to claim the loss. The broker, we decided, was in fact, following these strict rules, the letter of the law to note a wash sale which was negated once an additional few weeks passed.

Comment: David Schwartz has misinterpreted what a wash sale is. As Hart CO indicated, you can't have a wash sale when there is one purchase and one sale (or vice versa if short).  Schwartz misguidedly believes that the purchase is a replacement for the sale that will be sold.  Fairmark.com is a highly reputable tax web site. Below, Craig W has provided a quote as well as the link and it clearly states that buying shares is not the acquisition of replacement shares.

Answer (score 6):

**Addition:  With this edit, I add a citation from a well known and highly respected source, instead of merely quoting my experience with the IRS.**

As the OP described his purchase, and the sale 15 days later, he has a short term loss.  He can deduct this loss, first from any short term gains he has in the same year (or that have been carried forward); second (if there is any loss left) from any long term gains he has in the same year (or that have been carried forward); and third (if there is any loss left) take a $3,000 adjustment on his ordinary income. (An adjustment is like a deduction, but better, because it reduces your Adjusted Gross Income.) If there is still any loss left over, he can carry it forward to the next year.

**Wash Sale Citation:**  From *J.K.Lasser. Your Income Tax 2018* (typed from hard copy), page 558:

> **Loss on the sale of part of a stock lot bought less than 30 days ago:** If you buy stock and then, within 30 days, sell some of those
>   shares, a loss on the sale is deductible; the wash sale disallowance
>   rule does not apply.
>
> ....the wash sale rule does not apply to a loss sustained in a bone
>   fide sale made to reduce your market position.

(Obviously if, within 30 days, you then buy essentially what you originally bought and then sold, your loss is denied.)

Googling indicates the new tax law did not change the rules on wash sales, but I do not have a copy of this year's *J.K.Lasser*.

Other references, for example [A Primer on Wash Sales by Charles Schwab](https://www.schwab.com/resource-center/insights/content/a-primer-on-wash-sales) support Lasser's explanation.  So even if the transaction the OP describes is  technically a wash sale, it has no consequences, other than that of a short-term capital loss.

PS: Don't get hung up on the phrase "part of a stock" in the Lasser quote. It is there to make a more general case.  The Lasser quote applies to buy, then sell, all of the stock, too.

You don't need to consult a lawyer.  You made no second purchase within 30  days of the sale, before or after.   You might want to purchase a tax guide, such as J. K. Lasser, however.

**Afterthought:**  Is there a loophole here?  Will ask in a separate Q.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the purchase through which I acquired the shares I sold count as buying "substantially identical stock or securities" within 30 days before the sale, thus disallowing the loss? I feel like it shouldn't, but laws can get really weird. Citations would be appreciated, the more explicit the better.

Yes, it counts as a wash sale but no, it doesn't disallow the loss. 26 USC 1091(a) is umambiguous -- this is a wash sale.

But the law allows regulations to specify what happens to the disallowed loss but requires that the regulations shift that loss to an increase in basis to some unit of stock or securities. In this case, there is no place to shift the loss, so the only thing that can possibly happen is the basis stays with that sale.

If you did possess any other substantially identical stock or securities, you would have to consult the detailed regulations to see where the loss appears as an increase in basis.

See [26 USC 1091(c) and 26 USC 1091(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1091).

Comment: Again you make this nonsensical interpretation of the tax code.  A wash sale involves a realized loss and a substantially identical third transaction within the 60 day window (and everything in your link revolves around that).  In addition, when brokers report trading  on 1099-B and 8949 forms, they do not list simple buy and sell (or short and cover) round trips as a wash sale.  A round trip without a substantially equivalent replacement cannot be a wash sale.

Comment: @BobBaerker It's not an interpretation, it's what the statute actually says. 26 USC 1091(a) makes absolutely, unambiguously clear that this is a wash sale -- 
 there is a realized loss and there is an acquisition of a substantially identical asset within the 60 day window. Nothing in the statute says it must be a "third transaction". And, yes, many brokers do report these as wash sales and include both the decrease and increase in the same line item. (In fact, I'm pretty sure that the last time we had this discussion, it was explaining a report from a broker that did just that!)

Comment: @BobBaerker While I realize the intent is probably what you say, the law does not appear to say this. "where it appears that, within a period beginning 30 days before the date of such sale or disposition and ending 30 days after such date, the taxpayer has acquired ... substantially identical stock or securities,". Unless you are claiming that a share is not substantially identical to itself, buying a share and then selling the same share a week later while having no other holdings does indeed match this test following the letter of this law.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I thought I agreed with you, but now I am not so sure on this. The law states that "then no deduction shall be allowed under section 165" while the law allowing you to increase the basis on the other shares merely says "...basis of the stock or securities so sold or disposed of, increased or decreased...". It would appear if this is a wash sale the basis would indeed be increased but "no deduction shall be allowed" which negates the deduction entirely, even if the basis is changed.

Comment: IE: I buy 1 share for $1000, a week later I sell it for $500, if this is a wash sale, I can increase the basis of the sold shares "by the difference, if any, between the price at which the property was acquired and the price at which such substantially identical stock or securities were sold or otherwise disposed of."

So I increase the basis to $1500 and have made a loss of $1000, I however then cannot deduct this loss of $1000 because "In the case of any loss claimed to have been sustained from any sale or other disposition of shares [causing a wash]... then no deduction shall be allowed "

Comment: This position is absolutely incorrect.  These wash sale questions are almost always crazy hypotheticals asked by people who think wash sales actually matter.  A wash-sale is a tax issue.  If you buy within 30 days of a sale that resulted in a loss you add the loss to the cost basis of that purchase. You don't go resurrect closed positions to change the outcome, and certainly not to wash itself.  If you buy then sell at a loss, there is a 30 day window where if you buy again you must add the loss to the cost basis for tax purposes.  For 99% of investors and transactions that's all that matters.

Comment: @quid while this seems entirely sane, and probably what is intended, I cannot read this from the law as written unless a stock is not considered to be "substantially identical" to itself. It appears if it is, this law does indeed mean any holding held for less than 30 days is never deductible. I like your opinion but it is making a lot of assumptions that are not actually written in the text of the law...

Comment: It's got nothing to do with sanity.  Part of the law indicates that someone else (the IRS) will determine how wash sales are handled.  These zero experience attempts to explain what is an extremely simple and largely irrelevant tax issue drive me nuts.  This is not my *opinion* and the law absolutely does not indicate that ALL losses resulting from sales within 30 days of buy are never deductible.  That is a completely inane reading of the law, fully ignores the IRS guidance regarding share/unit matching and the handling of a disallowed loss, and the fundamentals of a transaction.

Comment: @quid I agree it seems bizarre and unbelievable but do you at least have a (reputable) source that specifies this is not the case as I have seen this asked a lot and it certainly does seem a naive reading would infer this? Call me pedantic if you like but naively reading this law does seem to produce this conclusion. I appreciate your disagreement but I would far more appreciate an answer or source which explains why this naive interpretation is not the case. I wouldn't want to do something that seems illegal when reading the law without some evidence it is ok...

Comment: David insists on focusing on the fact that there are two parts to the rules.  1. Is the sale a "wash sale?" and 2. Is the loss deductible.  Was there a loss resulting from the sale where there was any purchase within 30 days, sure.   So the answer to "is this a wash sale" is yes (technically).  But what's really being asked is "is this loss deductible" and the answer is: It will be UNLESS you buy again within 30 days.  I've written other answers on this topic, you are free to go read them.  This is akin to answering "I *can* but will I?" when someone asks "can you take out the trash?"

Comment: @quid That's precisely what my answer says. Yes, this is a wash. No, the loss winds up being allowed (though in the form of an increase in basis). This is important to understand because this is precisely how transactions like this are reported by most brokers. You will see both the disallowed loss and the increase in basis reported with the transaction. Congress chose to define a wash sale very broadly and then use regulations to nullify the effect where it doesn't make sense (though imperfectly as some crazy hypotheticals can show).

Comment: @Vality -You are incorrect about "matching the test".   Read the citation post by Craig W from Fairmark.com.  It clearly states that when you buy the shares that you sell within 30 days of realizing a loss (one purchase, one sale), the stock that you bought isn’t replacement stock for the stock you sold and the wash sale rule does not apply.

Comment: One other point.  Wash sales are an accounting and  taxation issue.  If you exit all positions by the end of the year and take no substantially identical positions in the following 30 days, you get to claim all losses regardless of whether they were wash sales or not.  If this had occurred, make a  “Do Not Trade List” to avoid violating the final exit date.  And though I doubt that it applies to anyone here, a trader who qualifies for and makes a Section 475 election for Trader Tax Status is eligible for mark-to-market (MTM) accounting, which exempts him  from wash sale losses.

Comment: @BobBaerker The Fairmark citation doesn't address the question asked. For example, it says that the transaction isn't a wash sale using the commonsense understanding of the term "wash sale". That's a different question from whether it's considered a wash sale under US law by 26 USC 1091(a). Fairmark chose a way to simplify and explain the consequences of the rule, but that's not sufficient to answer this question which asks why and how that simplification fits with rules like 26 USC 1091(a) which appear to say something else. Fairmark doesn't address that issue at all, I do.

Answer (score -2):

This would appear to depend on ones interpretation of 26 U.S. Code § 1091 (a).

> In the case of any loss claimed to have been sustained from any sale
>   or other disposition of shares of stock or securities where it appears
>   that, within a period beginning 30 days before the date of such sale
>   or disposition and ending 30 days after such date, the taxpayer has
>   acquired (by purchase or by an exchange on which the entire amount of
>   gain or loss was recognized by law), or has entered into a contract or
>   option so to acquire, substantially identical stock or securities,
>   then no deduction shall be allowed under section 165 unless the
>   taxpayer is a dealer in stock or securities and the loss is sustained
>   in a transaction made in the ordinary course of such business. For
>   purposes of this section, the term “stock or securities” shall, except
>   as provided in regulations, include contracts or options to acquire or
>   sell stock or securities.

This would indeed be a wash sale if this statute considers a stock or security to be "substantially identical" to itself. However it is not clear to me if this is so or not as parsing it as layman it isn't clear if an object can be called "substantially identical" to itself.

I suppose if you want a rock solid interpretation of this law you would be better of speaking to a lawyer or judge than people on the internet.

Comment: The point of "substantially identical" rather than "identical" is to prevent people from evading the wash sale by purchasing another security that provided the same exposure as the original one. It would defeat the point of the rule if it excluded an identical security.

Answer (score -3):

Agreeing with @DavidSchwartz, it is a wash sale, but you can still realize the loss immediately. Remember a wash sale just delays realizing the loss, it doesn't negate it completely (unless a tax-advantaged account is involved). But if there are no replacement shares left to adjust the basis for, the loss can be realized immediately.

[Fairmark](https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/wash/wash-sales-and-replacement-stock/) has extensive information on this topic. Their first example addresses this situation:

> 1: Selling All
>
> > On June 1 you buy 200 shares of XYZ for $10,000. On June 12 you sell all 200 shares for $8,000 (a loss of $2,000).
>
> Most people wouldn’t even think about applying the wash sale rule here. You know instinctively it shouldn’t apply, even though there’s a purchase of identical stock less than 31 days before the sale. Your instincts are correct: the wash sale rule doesn’t apply because the stock you bought isn’t replacement stock for the stock you sold. That’s true because you sold the same stock you bought.

Comment: Both you and David Schwartz are incorrect.  Your link and the segment that you quoted clearly states that it's not a wash sale: "Most people wouldn’t even think about applying the wash sale rule here. You KNOW INSTINCTIVELY IT SHOULDN'T APPLY, even though there’s a purchase of identical stock less than 31 days before the sale. Your instincts are correct: THE WASH SALE RULE DOESN'T APPLY because the stock you bought *** ISN'T REPLACEMENT STOCK *** for the stock you sold. That’s true because you sold the same stock you bought."

Comment: @BobBaerker It's semantics anyway since everybody agrees the full loss can be realized. But I've had this exact scenario and Fidelity labeled it a wash sale, and I'm confident in their interpretation. I think Fairmark is just being imprecise with their language, and by saying "the wash sale rule doesn't apply" they mean the delay of realizing the loss.

Comment: @BobBaerker Congress could have chosen to implement the wash sale rule that way, but they didn't. They picked another way that produces the same effect.

Answer (score -5):

I'm editing this answer because the OP edited the original question, clarifying his premise.  If you buy substantially identical identical stock or securities" within 30 days before or after realizing a lose, the loss is  disallowed. Note that disallowed means that the loss is deferred. It does not mean that it is disallowed and lost forever.  This involves 3 transactions if long (two buys and a sell).

The OP has changed his wording to clarify that he meant one buy and a sale within 30 says of his purchase.  Although David Schwartz insists that this is a wash sale, his misinterpretation  is incorrect. His claim is refuted   by Craig W's link to Fairmark.com, a reputable taxation web site.

Furthermore, every web site that I have ever read that provides an example of a wash sale violation utilizes 3 transactions.  I have never seen one that utilized two transaction and I doubt that anyone claiming that two transactions is a wash sale can find a reputable citation.  Believing that 2 transactions constitutes a wash sale violation is a misguided personal interpretation of tax law.

Back to the OP's question.  Buying a security and selling it with 30 days does not constitute a wash sale.  The same holds true for shorting.

---

It appears that Fairmark.com is inadequate for some here. Per H&R Block:

> The wash sale rules are designed to prevent people from selling investments and then buying the same stock back. Investors do this for the sole purpose of:
>
> Creating a deductible loss
>
> Using the loss to offset other shares sold for a gain
>   Still keeping the stock or security in their investment portfolio
>
> You can’t sell a stock or mutual fund at a loss and then buy it again it within 30 days just to claim the losses.
>
> You’ll need to figure the basis for shares sold in a wash sale. When you do, add the amount of disallowed loss to the basis of the shares that caused the wash sale. These are the new shares you received. By doing this, you defer the loss, but it’s not disallowed for good. You’ll get the benefit of the loss when you eventually sell the new shares (unless it’s another wash sale!).
>
> You also have a wash sale if both of these apply:
>
> You sell stock at a loss.
>
> Your spouse — or a corporation you control — buys the same stock within the 30 days before and after the date of the sale.
>
> Also, you might have bought fewer shares of stock or securities than you sold. If so, only the number of shares you bought is subject to the wash-sale rules.

In all of these tax related web sites, wash sale discussion involves REPLACEMENT shares not a round trip loss involving a single purchase and a single sale.  Believing that to be a wash sale is misguided.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the hypothetical situation. Unlike example 1, there are only two transactions. I buy shares, and then I sell them. There is no second purchase, and I do not own any shares at the end.

Comment: When I say "the purchase of the very same shares I sold", I mean the purchase through which I acquired the shares I sold, not a purchase of replacement shares. There's no new stock to adjust the basis of.

Comment: If that's the case then you have formulated your question poorly and you have incorrectly involved the Wash Sale rule. The Wash Sale rule applies to two purchases and one sale where the second purchase is within 30 days before or after the date the loss is realized.  If you only had one purchase and one sale and that round trip transaction resulted in a loss, you're done and you claim  that loss on your tax return (non sheltered account).  The only reason that the loss  would then be deferred would be that you have annual losses (including carry forwards) that exceed $3,000

Comment: Do you have a citation for this, and can you edit your answer? What you describe is how I think it would make sense for things to work, but that doesn't mean it's how things do work.

Comment: You want a citation that explains  what a realized capital loss is???  Read page 48 of IRS Pub 550.  And you want me to edit my answer for what purpose, to move the comment information 12 inches up the page?

Comment: @BobBaerker comments are supposed to be ephemeral, if you've worked out something that clarifies your answer in the comments then it makes sense to integrate that into the answer itself.

Comment: I want a citation that the wash sale rule does not apply to this transaction. I am aware of the concept of a realized capital loss. As for why the answer should be edited, aside from what Ganesh pointed out, a wrong answer with a correction in the comments is still a wrong answer unless edited.

Comment: What needed to be edited was your question.   Having done that, it doesn't change my answer or my comment.  Now you want a citation for something that doesn't exist?  LOL.  Don't hold your breath for that to be found.  Here's my last comment: Asked and answered.  Accept it or don't accept it.

Comment: Saying "you have incorrectly involved the Wash Sale rule," isn't helpful. How to correctly apply the wash sale rule is the essence of the question.

Comment: @The Photon: If you start with a faulty premise, how do you prove that it's true?  IOW, how do you apply the wash sale rule when there is no wash sale?  Figure that out and then post the answer for us.

Comment: The point is to explain why there's no wash sale, given that, as OP correctly points out, the rules presented by the IRS seem to imply that there is.

Comment: @ThePhoton There is a wash sale. That's unambiguously clear. The rule is very simple and very straightforward. The question is what the consequences are.