# Do wash sale rules apply for partial sales within 30 days?

Tags: united-states, taxes, wash-sale

I have already looked at [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109535/does-selling-shares-within-30-days-of-purchase-count-as-a-wash-sale) and its answers, but I have a slightly different question.

Suppose I buy 100 shares of a stock on July 1, and two weeks later, on July 15, sell 50 of those 100 shares at a price lower than I paid for them.

**Could the IRS argue that the 50 shares I did not sell constitutes a purchase within 30 days of the sale, and therefore consider my loss a wash sale and prevent me from deducting it?**

As a slight variation, does it matter whether I made one order or two on the same day to purchase the original 100 shares?

Comment: (to the member voting to close) The question is clear. What clarification do you want? It may be a duplicate, but that's a different issue.

Comment: It is not a wash sale (see my comments below).

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD - kinda curious why you deleted your correct answer.

Comment: I would recommend unaccepting the currently-accepted answer until a more authoritative source is provided. It's pretty clear that this is _not_ what the rule was intended to mean and none of the examples provided in the CFR (or anywhere else that I can see) anticipate such a use of the rule.

Comment: @reirab Again, you can dislike the law as much as you want, but what I cited is **the actual law**. So unless you can show a court precedent interpreting it in the way you want - your personal opinions on the matter don't really make any difference during the IRS audit.

Comment: @littleadv Minor quibble: It's regulation, not law. CFR = Code of Federal Regulations. If it were law, it would be in the U.S. Code instead. At any rate, while I agree that a court precedent (or statement from the Office of Chief Counsel at the IRS) would be ideal, the regulation having been around for half a century with no suggestion from the IRS that it should be interpreted as you describe for something that happens many times every day suggests that your interpretation is probably not the correct one. More so since it doesn't fit with the purpose of the regulation.

Comment: @littleadv But, of course, the same applies to your answer: If you can find court precedent, official statement from the IRS (or even a qualified tax professional,) etc. that supports your claim for how the regulation should be interpreted, that would be much more useful than just your opinion on the correct interpretation. It is not unusual for regulations (or even actual laws) to have interpretations in practice different than what their plain text might suggest, especially when such an interpretation wouldn't make sense in light of the purpose of the law or regulation.

Comment: @reirab I quoted the law, literally. In my view there's nothing to interpret, it's pretty clear. I don't need to prove a negative. You're challenging me - prove it.

Comment: As to CFR not being the law - it very much is. CFR is a legal authority, and is the government's interpretation of the law. Until the court rules otherwise, CFR is how the government will interpret the law. But feel free to read through the [26 USC 1091](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1091) if it makes you happier. It does refer you to the regulations, though, which is... CFR.

Comment: @littleadv I'm not asking you to prove a negative. I'm asking you to provide a qualified source that actually agrees with your interpretation. You're the one writing an answer. The burden of proof to support it is on you. If the IRS were actually interpreting it as you say, then there should be ample evidence of this, as the regulation has been around for half a century and it's a very common situation which virtually every trader has encountered. If it's really a thing, it should be well documented in IRS taxpayer instructions as well as sites that cover investments and taxation.

Comment: I did provide exactly that. I'm not sure what other evidence you expect from me. You say "prove that the IRS interprets the law this way" - I gave you the regulation, which is the interpretation of the law, and you respond with "now prove that the IRS is actually applying the regulation". That's a bit ridiculous, I don't have visibility into every ROs' audit report, what do you expect me to show you here? *it should be well documented in IRS taxpayer instructions* - yes, it is, in Publication 550 which I quoted to the letter.

Comment: @littleadv Nothing that you've quoted (and nothing in either 26 CFR 1.1091 or Pub 550 at all) suggests that the IRS interprets the "substantially identical stocks or securities" to include the actual shares that were being sold (or other shares purchased at the same time as those.) The concept of the wash sale rule possibly applying to the original purchase is not suggested at all in any of those sources. And common sense says that that's obviously not what it was intended to mean. While the law or regulation _could_ contradict common sense, that would need an actual source to back it up.

Comment: @reirab I'm not sure why you're saying that. The plain text suggests you're wrong. The definition in the CFR is pretty clear, and makes no distinction between the initial and subsequent purchases. I know you want the reality to be different, but you're making no argument other than "I don't like this".

Comment: @littleadv You're not sure why I'm saying that the wash sale rule obviously wasn't intended to limit deducting short-term losses on positions held less than 31 days as opposed to actual wash sales? The point of the rule was to keep you from selling and repurchasing the same security for the sole purpose of realizing a loss for tax purposes. Hence the name "wash sale." I freely admit that the CFR's wording is poor (not uncommon for the CFR,) but that's pretty clearly not what it was _intended_ to mean.

Comment: @reirab legislative intent is important in law suits, but not when you're arguing with an RO during an audit. During an audit you can only rely on the law, regulations, and the IRS official guidance (revenue rulings or PLR if applicable to you). I've cited the law and the regulation, and the IRS *unofficial* guidance (the pub 550). I didn't go through all the RRs, but at a quick glance I didn't find any where this would be discussed. Because to me the text of the regulation is trivial. I don't understand why for you it isn't.

Comment: @littleadv I have already described that: Because this is something that happens probably millions of times every single tax year for the last half a century and the IRS has said nothing as far as I can tell that suggests they interpret "substantially identical stocks or securities" the same way your answer does. Not a single source I've seen agrees with you. If you can't provide a source clearly stating that the IRS interprets it that way, then you should at least say so in your answer and suggest consulting an actual tax professional.

Comment: @reirab "*suggest consulting an actual tax professional*" - if people are stupid enough to act on a random internet post, that's not my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could the IRS argue that the 50 shares I did not sell constitutes a purchase within 30 days of the sale, and therefore consider my loss a wash sale and prevent me from deducting it?

Yes. See the [Publication 550](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550#en_US_2022_publink100010601):

> A wash sale occurs when you sell or trade stock or securities at a loss and within 30 days **before** or after the sale you:
>
> Buy substantially identical stock or securities, ...

So you bought the 100 shares on July 1st and sold 50 of them on July 15th - you end up with a wash sale and the basis of the remaining 50 will be adjusted for the loss.

The difference from the original question you linked to was that there were no shares remaining in that scenario. There, the OP sold *all* the shares, and didn't repurchase. This is not the same in your scenario.

---

There's some confusion in the comments about the concept of "replacement shares". Note that this concept is not mentioned in the text I quoted from the Publication. It's a term used loosely to explain what a wash sale is, but the "replacement" doesn't actually need to be actual physical replacement. If you want to go into more details - feel free to read through [26 CFR 1.1091-1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.1091-1):

> (a) A taxpayer cannot deduct any loss claimed to have been sustained from the sale or other disposition of stock or securities if, **within a period beginning 30 days *before* the date of such sale or disposition and ending 30 days after such date** (referred to in this section as the 61-day period), **he has acquired** (by purchase or by an exchange upon which the entire amount of gain or loss was recognized by law), or has entered into a contract or option so to acquire, **substantially identical stock or securities**.

There's no mentioning of "replacement" or exclusion of the initial purchase in this text.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  A wash sale is when an investor sells a stock or security at a loss and repurchases the same or a substantially identical security within 30 days before or after realizing that loss.  The OP did not acquire substantially identical shares.  The original purchase cannot be considered to be "replacement shares".

Comment: @BobBaerker Nothing is said about "replacement" -- any purchase within 30 days counts.

Comment: So if I buy 1000 shares for $10 each, sell 999 of them the next day for $9, I end up with a basis of $1009 in the sole remaining share?

Comment: @BobBaerker *The original purchase cannot be considered to be "replacement shares".* - Citation needed. I provided a clear basis for my explanation, note that "replacement" doesn't appear in it.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica you end up with $11 basis for the sole remaining share, $998 deductible loss, and $1 disallowed wash sale loss. You have to match assets 1:1, so if you only have 1 share left - you end up with loss on one share being disallowed. In the OP's example, he kept 50 and sold 50, so everything is disallowed.

Comment: Another thought experiment: day0: buy 64 shares for $10; day1: sell 32 shares for $9; day2: sell 16 shares for $9...etc...day6: sell 1 share for $9. That's $63 of losses, is that $62 deductible and $11 basis on the one remaining share, or $0 deductible and $73 basis on the share?

Comment: @littleadv: sorry, I was eliding a binary progression of sales. Each day we sell half the remaining holding, and 1 share would be left after day 6.

Comment: Then you'll have $31 basis: $10 original, and 6 times loss on one share for each of the sales, compounded. Isn't wash sale rules fun for kids? Awesome exercise in arithmetic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145062/discussion-between-gs-apologise-to-monica-and-littleadv).

Comment: @littleadv - I suggest that you google "replacement shares, shorting' and read the material out there.  Or if you wish, provide a citation that supports your premise that original shares become substantially identical shares when you sell one or more of them at a loss and therefore cannot deduct the realized loss. Just curious, have you ever shorted shares? And I note that in another comment, you utilize 'replacement shares' in you answer.

Comment: @BobBaerker I cited the CFR, which is a legal authority. What's your counterargument?

Comment: Here is at least one source that disagrees with this analysis: https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/wash/wash-sales-and-replacement-stock/

Comment: According to this theory where the initial purchase counts for purposes of the wash sale rule - ignoring the obvious fact that this isn't what the wash sale rule was intended to do - the shares that would be matched whose basis should be increased by the loss are... exactly the same shares that were sold. Thus, even if this did apply, the net effect would seem to be nothing. I'm not a tax professional, but I'm guessing a real tax professional or tax lawyer would laugh at the idea that the wash sale rule could apply to the original purchase, poor wording of the CFR notwithstanding.

Comment: @reirab I think the theory here is that the 50 unsold shares are the ones whose basis is increased.

Comment: "More or less stock bought than sold.

If the number of shares of substantially identical stock or securities you buy within 30 days before or after the sale is either more or less than the number of shares you sold, you must determine the particular shares to which the wash sale rules apply. You do this by matching the shares bought with an equal number of the shares sold. Match the shares bought in the same order that you bought them, beginning with the first shares bought. The shares or securities so matched are subject to the wash sale rules. " (from your first link)

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica That theory would seem to contradict the ordering rules in the CFR and Pub 550, though. If the initial purchase does indeed count, then the ordering rules for which shares are being sold and which ones triggered the lack of deductibility are the same, so it would seem to be the shares that were sold whose basis would change (which, of course, makes no sense.)

Comment: @reirab I have yet to meet a lawyer who'd laugh at the law because it doesn't make sense to *you*. As to your reasoning - I can claim just as easily that the sale of 50 was not in the same order than the purchase (especially if the OP has other positions and still chose this lot, or other history of non-FIFO recognition), just as easily. Bottom line - the law is what the law is and if you want to contest it you go to court, or look for precedent where it was contested before, you don't snipe nonsense from your couch.

Comment: @littleadv - A wash sale comprises two transactions, i.e., the sale of a security at a loss and the REPURCHASE  of the security within 30 days before or after realizing that loss.  Read IRS Publication 550.  Or read about it at Fairmark.com or Greentrader.com, two well known reputable tax trading sites.

Comment: @BobBaerker thanks for the reference. The IRS Publication 550 is the one I quoted from in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. To be a wash sale you have to sell a stock and buy it back within 30 days. The fact that you only sold some of your shares doesn't make the shares you didn't sell "count as a buy". Not selling is not the same thing as buying, and the IRS doesn't pretend that it is.

Comment: A wash sale is a sale at a loss with buying replacement shares within 30 days **before** or after the sale.

Comment: Here's the confusion, OP asks "Could the IRS argue that the 50 shares I did not sell constitutes a purchase..." The answer to that question is no, but OP also asks: "Do wash sale rules apply for partial sales within 30 days?" Yes.

Comment: @HartCO Yes. As I understand the question, OP presented these two ideas as opposites, so yes to one is no to the other. That's what I tried to say in my answer above. If it wasn't clear, sorry.

Comment: It's not two questions. The question is the part after "and therefore"; the first part is just their mistaken premise.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  The OP did not buy replacement shares so it is not a wash sale.   His deduction is legitimate.

Comment: @BobBaerker I added CFR to my references on top of the IRS Publication. Do you want to may be reconsider your conviction?

Comment: If you bought the shares and then sold the same shares within 30 days, is that a wash sale because the purchase of the "replacement shares" was within 30 days? Even though they are in fact the shares that you sold? I must admit that I've never thought of this. That seems irrational to me. Maybe I'll try it just as an experiment and see if my broker lists it as a wash sale on my 1098. Does anyone here have any information other than "that's what the rules sound like they mean to me"? Because debating what makes sense to you versus what makes sense to me is not at all the same as ...

Comment: ... what makes sense to the IRS.

Comment: @littleadv - No I would not want to reconsider my conviction.  Your citation explains this in sections 'a'.   It discusses  acquiring substantially identical stock or securities within +/- 30 days of realizing the loss.  That means replacement shares not the original shares.  What you are missing in this is what is defined as replacement shares.  An initial purchase cannot replace itself.

Comment: @Jay - The purpose of the wash sale is to prevent the closing of a stock or option position in order to deduct a loss and then buying it back in order to maintain the position (all of this pertains to shorting as well).  Hence the 60 day window. Original purchase shares cannot be shares that are purchased 30 days before or 30 days after realizing a loss.  They are mutually exclusive.  The mistake many are making here is considering initial purchase shares to be replacement shares as well.  And yes, I have been shorting shares extensively for the past 20 years.

Comment: @BobBaerker I went through the CFR section I cited, and there's no concept of "replacement shares" discussed there at all. Where are you bringing this from? *Original purchase shares cannot be shares that are purchased 30 days before or 30 days after realizing a loss* - on what legal authority are you making this claim? *They are mutually exclusive* - says who?

Comment: @Jay what "makes sense" doesn't matter. What matters is "what the law says". I cited the law. I advise you and others with dissenting opinions to provide a legal reference. I can be convinced, I've been wrong before, but not by the argument "I'm right because I did shorts and googled stuff".

Comment: @littleadv Yes, that was my point. "Sounds right to me" is not the same as "the law says". The problem is, you say you cite the law, true, you did. But then you give an interpretation of the law which I and others find counter-intuitive and unlikely. You may be right. Again, what matters is not what sounds reasonable to you and me but what the IRS and tax courts say. But to say, "I quoted the law and if you read it a certain way it sort of kind of sounds like it means this" is not a definitive argument.

Comment: @littleadv - A wash sale comprises two transactions, i.e., the sale of a security at a loss and the REPURCHASE  of the security within 30 days before or after realizing that loss.  Read IRS Publication 550.

Answer (score 1):

IRS doesn't care about how the shares are grouped into lots in each sale, each share is considered individually.

So for this purpose, you had 100 purchases on July 1. You sold 50 of them at a loss on July 15. Each of those 50 sales is a wash sale, because it's within 30 days of a purchase.

You can ignore the 50 shares you didn't sell for now. Of course they're treated as a purchase, since you purchased them. But since you haven't sold them yet, you don't mention them on your tax return.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  A wash sale is when an investor sells a stock or security at a loss and repurchases the same or a substantially identical security within 30 days before or after realizing that loss.  The OP did not acquire substantially identical shares.  The original purchase cannot be considered replacement shares.

Comment: It's 30 days before or after. So the original purchase is considered a "repurchase".

Comment: LOL.  An initial purchase can be a repurchase as well.